# Library to manipulate terminal space?

Tags: c++, linux, terminal

I want to make a rogue-like game for my assignment. I need something to let me handle the x and y pixels on the terminal screen as well as key events, so I can control my character. Also, will it be able to repaint a region of a terminal only? i.e. I don't want to repaint the terminal every time I move my character because it would create blinking effect. I just want to repaint the previous position and the next position of my character.

*Edit*: I want to program it in C++ under Linux.

Comment: Windows?  Linux?  OS X?  iPhone :-)?  Consider adding your platform to the tags.

Comment: Presumably you mean a *window* and not a *terminal*, since terminals display characters not pixels.

Comment: Characters are ok as well. But, in Windows, it has APIs, which can manipulate console x and y. Does linux have a library to manipulate that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your target is a command line application in a linux environment programmed with C++, I would suggest that you take a look at the [ncurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) library.

Comment: There are also ports of ncurses available for Windows which make using it a fairly portable operation.

Comment: Exactly the library I would recommend for a linux environment.